# How to reset my keyboard mapping file

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have somehow managed to corrupt my "us" keyboard file using nano. Whenever I try to select a US keyboard, I get an error message.

Does anyone know where to download the original file?

For what it's worth,

```
setxkbmap us
```

also throws an "error loading new keyboard description" .

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall xkb-data
```